# Matlab Saveas Error in 2013a

Tags: matlab

I just updated from 2012a to 2013a and now I'm getting a strange error when I try to save a figure as a jpg, using the same code that worked in 2012a. Here's the code:

```
h=figure;
plot(JDAYs(timesteps),y1(timesteps),JDAYs(timesteps),y2(timesteps));
legend('W2 output','RBF results')
xlabel('JDAY')
ylabel('T deg C')
title( strcat('Node ', num2str(node),' - T S',num2str(Seg),' L',num2str(Lay),', RMSE=', num2str(RMSE(node,1))))
name = strcat('time series 18 to 1000\Node ', num2str(node),' - T S',num2str(Seg),' L',num2str(Lay));
saveas(h,name, 'jpg');
close(h)
```

I'm getting this error, even though I have a folder in the current directory named "time series 18 to 1000":

```
Error using saveas (line 115)
Invalid or missing path: time series 18 to 1000\Node1 - T S2 L3
```

I then tried to save in the current folder:

```
name = strcat('Node ', num2str(node),' - T S',num2str(Seg),' L',num2str(Lay));
```

and get this error:

```
Error using name (line 103)
Cannot create output file '.\Node1 - T S2 L3.jpg'

Error in print (line 209)
pj = name( pj );

Error in saveas (line 154)
print( h, name, ['-d' dev{i}] )
```

This code worked in 2012a, and if I manually save (File->Save as) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code i used (i created the "time series 18 to 1000" folder), and it works on my computer (matlab r2010a):

```
node = 1;
Seg = 2;
Lay = 3;
RMSE = @(x) x*4;
h=figure;
plot(rand(1,5));
legend('W2 output')
xlabel('JDAY')
ylabel('T deg C')
title( strcat('Node ', num2str(node),' - T S',num2str(Seg),' L',num2str(Lay),', RMSE=', num2str(RMSE(node))))
name = strcat('time series 18 to 1000\Node ', num2str(node),' - T S',num2str(Seg),' L',num2str(Lay),'.jpg')
saveas(h,name, 'jpg');
close(h)
```

Comment: That folder does exist. Like I said above, I also tried saving it to the current directory folder (removed "time series 18 to 1000\") and still got an error back.

Comment: @Amy sorry i misunderstood. I'll check to see where could be your problem.

Comment: @Amy I created the "time series 18 to 1000" folder and it worked with the updated code i posted in my answer.

Comment: Are you using Matlab 2013a?

Comment: @Amy as mentionned, R2010a.

Comment: I see your update now. My code above worked fine in 2012a, but now it won't work in 2013a...

Comment: @Amy make sure you add the '.jpg' at the end of the name in the `strcat` command.

Comment: I tried that as well (although it wasn't necessary in 2012a), but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Amy Because in R2010a, with the code i posted, if i remove the '.jpg' at the end of `name`, I'm getting the same error as you. So it's definitely something related to the `name` variable. What's your output for the `name` variable?

Comment: I figured it out - the path+filename I was trying was longer than the maximum allowed in Windows (260 characters, I think). The code above works if I try to save the figure in a folder "up." So it wasn't a Matlab issue after all...